# How to set up dragging on trackpad?

Tags: macos, trackpad, ui

All fine, then suddenly I'm not able to drag with my trackpad. 
I can not find an option about how to change settings and I have no idea what happened?!
Any idea someone how to make it back to normal?

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Preferences → Trackpad and make sure Three finger drag is enabled.

[image]